# Set View height to 0dp and weight to 1 programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-layout-weight

When creating `GridView` via xml I use the below code, but how could I achieve that programmatically during runtime?

```
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
GridView YOUR_GRID_VIEW =(GridView )findViewById(R.id.GridView )
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                       /*width*/ ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               /*height*/ 0,
               /*weight*/ 1.0f
                );
                YOUR_GRID_VIEW.setLayoutParams(param);
```

`LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` is for width, 0 for Height and 1.0f is for weight

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `layout_weight` in xml, that means, that the parent layout of `GridView` is `LinearLayout`.

Having a reference to a `GridView`, that is already attached to view hierarchy, you can simply get `LayoutParams` of that view, cast it to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and perform necessary changes:

```
    GridView gridView = ...;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
    params.weight = 1;
    params.height = 0;
    gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Otherwise, if you are constructing `GridView` from scratch, you should create `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` on your own:

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = ...;
    GridView gridView = new GridView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
              new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                          /* height */ 0,
                          /* weight */ 1);
    linearLayout.addView(gridView, params);
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated :)